# How to convert purpose token into user identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, identity

We are using owin authentication in our application. We are able to use authentication and identity through **ApplicationCookie**. For this we use access token code like and it is working fine.

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization")))
                {
                    if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
                    {
                        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
                        string token = queryString.Get("access_token");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                        {
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { string.Format("Bearer {0}", token) });
                        }
                    }
                }

                await next();
            });
```

The problem is some functionality we want without login and using token which is purpose token we can say reset password token or some specific purpose token.

Currently we are using application cookies you can see code here

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                CookieHttpOnly = false,
                CookieName = CookieNames.FiboAuthentication,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => 
                        {
                            var api = Startup.CreateDatabaseApi();
                            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, api);
                        })
                }
            });
```

There is any way to use purpose token to authenticate or create identity then we can use this identity in authorization and our authentication flow same.

Please suggest best way. Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid your question is a bit unclear, what is purpose token?

Comment: thank youu. Purpose token is nothing but the token code which we are using reset password like this we created custom token.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a controller that allows anonymous and reset your pwd based on the username.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string username)
        {
        }
```

Comment: We are already tried with [AllowAnonymous] but some security issue that is not good practice.

Comment: ok, if passwor reset can be made by each user you can use the token for each user, if the reset can be made by an admin user you can use its token and it cover all the cases, in any case you can have an user and its token.